# How to get a value from other table if it has one to many relation in Eloquent laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables.

```
 1. Staff <br/>
    id | fname | lname | department

 2. Department<br/>
    id | name
```

There is a relation between Staff and Department. Department has many staff and Staff have a one department. Now I am trying to fetch data of staff. So instead of `department` in Staff table I should get name from `department` table.

Here is my model -
`Staff Model`

```
class Staff extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'staff';

    protected $fillable = ['fname', 'lname', 'department'];

    function departments(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'department');
    }
}
```

And - `Department Model`

```
class Department extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'departments';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'updated_at'];

    function staff(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Staff', 'department');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I am trying to fetch all staffs but I am getting department's id. I need a name of that department. How can it be possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for name of department, fetch data like this `$example->departments->name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has one to many relationship `department`, you need to change `staff model`
Check -

```
class Staff extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'staff';

    protected $fillable = ['fname', 'lname', 'department'];

    function departments(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

And now if you wanna fetch all staff info.

In your `controller` -

```
public function index(){
 $data = Staff::with('departments')->find(1);
return $data->departments->name;
}
```

Hopefully it will work.